# Error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "time"

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Im trying to write java MapReduce code and keep getting the error:

```
Error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "time"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
at TokenizerMapper.map(Unknown Source)
at TokenizerMapper.map(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:793)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1917)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

The mapper code in question is the following

```
    public class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private final IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text data = new Text();
    String[] transactionData = new String[5];

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {


        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(), ",");


        while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                transactionData[i] = itr.nextToken();
            }


            Long timestamp = Long.parseLong(transactionData[2]);
            Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(timestamp);
            LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of("GMT"));
            int year = ldt.getYear(); //e.g 2009
            Month month = ldt.getMonth(); //e.g JANUARY

            String time = month.toString() + ":" + Integer.toString(year);

            data.set(time);

            context.write(data, one);
        }
    }
}
```

It is supposed to take the 3rd value in each line of a csv dataset, which is a number, convert this to string, convert that to long and use the long to find the month and year.

where am i going wrong? thanks.

edit// Sample entry:

```
0e3e2357e806b6cdb1f70b54c3a3a17b6714ee1f0e68bebb44a74b1efd512098,00000000839a8e6886ab5951d76f411475428afc90947ee320161bbf18eb6048,1231469665,1,1
```

Comment: We love having you here: what does your data look like?

Comment: Your data has the word `time` in the column where you're expecting a number.  Is this text from the header row perhaps?  Did you forget to skip the header row of your data?

Comment: Thanks, added sample entry, the data is a list of bitcoin transactions and im trying to use hadoop to find number of transactions each month.

Comment: Is there a header row in your data set that you're not ignoring?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the problem is a header, just replace the line that causes the problem:

```
Long timestamp = Long.parseLong(transactionData[2]);
```

with

```
Long timestamp = 0L;
try {
    timestamp = Long.parseLong(transactionData[2]);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    return;
}
```

So if the value is invalid the method will terminate without crashing.

Comment: So if there's a line of header data, then no data at all should get mapped?  This solution makes no sense to me.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem no it skips only that line. The method works for **1** line. Isn't this obvious? Why do you think OP accepted the answer?

Comment: Well, I don't know why OP accepted your answer.  But if you put YOUR code into THEIR method, the `return;` statement causes their method to end without mapping any data.

Comment: *Well, I don't know why OP accepted your answer* then why don't you ask him first if you have any doubts? Why does anyone accept an answer if this is not the solution for him?

Comment: My apologies for not responding earlier, This solution worked for myself and several others stuck on the same assignment question. - Thanks for help